# Jsoup Android Fetching Info

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

Hello Guys I Have been having Issues with Jsoup, I am basically trying to Fetch(Parse) Info from this site into my app
http://websemantics.co.uk/tutorials/accessibility_workshop/sessions/session2/03.data_tables/01.simple_data_tables/

I want to fetch the Number of Candidates colum into separte strings of Biology Math, Science etc. with the value parsed and attached to the string. How can I do it, Can you give an example code?

My take on this would be:

```
//Get The Site and Parse it
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://websemantics.co.uk/tutorials/accessibility_workshop/sessions/session2/03.data_tables/01.simple_data_tables/").get();
//Select Table
 Element table = doc.select("table").first();
        Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td").iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("text : "+iterator.next().text());
String Math = text();
```

I tried a different way but is not giving anything

```
Element table = doc.select("table").first();
                 Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td").iterator();
                 while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    Element row1 = table.select( "td:eq(1)").first();
                    String rowno1 = row1.text(); 
                                               Element row2= table.select( "td:eq(1)").first();
                    String rowno2 = row2.text();
```

I don't know how to get further with this, Can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want **lines**, not **columns**, so you should get `<tr>`s, not `<td>`s of the first table.

So, change your code from:

```
table.select("td").iterator();
```

To:

```
table.select("tr").iterator();
```

That's it!

**Working example** (I also added something to help you with assigning the subjects to the variables):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Get The Site and Parse it
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://websemantics.co.uk/tutorials/accessibility_workshop/sessions/session2/03.data_tables/01.simple_data_tables/").get();
    // Select Table
    Element table = doc.select("table").first();

    String math = "";
    Iterator<Element> lines = table.select("tr").iterator();
    while (lines.hasNext()) {
        Element line = lines.next();
        System.out.println("text : "+line.text());
        if (line.text().contains("Mathematics")) {
            math = line.text();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("MATH: "+math);
}
```

Output:

```
text : Subject Number of candidates A B C D E U
text : Totals 176 28 37 32 32 25 15
text : Mathematics 36 6 7 8 6 5 4
text : English 34 6 8 7 7 5 1
text : Chemistry 40 6 9 9 7 5 4
text : Physics 36 6 7 8 6 5 4
text : Biology 30 4 6 7 6 5 2
MATH: Mathematics 36 6 7 8 6 5 4
```